# [__NSCFSet iName]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uialertview

I just do not seem to follow this.

This is my code

```
-(void)saveClicked:(id)sender{
    Item *item=[[Item alloc]init];
    item.iName=nameField.text;

    if ([appDelegate.list containsObject:item]) {
    //currentItem and item are object of class Item
    //currentItem was declared in the headerfile and synchronized
        currentItem=item;
        NSString *msg=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ already exists in your Instock list",item.iName];
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:msg delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"edit",nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (buttonIndex==0) {
    }
    else {
        //getting the error here
        NSLog(@"%@",currentItem.iName);
    }
}
```

ERROR:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFSet iName]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5e280b0'
```

I have no clue why this is happening. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you releasing `currentItem` anywhere? It looks to be the case.

Comment: @Deepak: only in the Dealloc method

Comment: Based on only the code provided, there isn't any reason for `currentItem` to be deallocated. What about item?

Comment: yes. I release **item** after showing the alert view.

Comment: ah....I commented out releasing item and it works.

Comment: But that will create a leak when you're setting the `currentItem` the second time as you would be simply reassigning without releasing the old value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume you have `currentItem` as `retain` property , Try with using below with your `saveClicked:`

```
    self.currentItem = item;
```

So, you code should be ...

```
-(void)saveClicked:(id)sender{
    Item *item=[[Item alloc]init];
    item.iName=nameField.text;

    if ([appDelegate.list containsObject:item]) {
    //currentItem and item are object of class Item
    //currentItem was declared in the headerfile and synchronized

        self.currentItem = item;

        NSString *msg=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ already exists in your Instock list",item.iName];
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:msg delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"edit",nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }
    [item release];
}
```

Comment: ah...how did i miss this :(
Thanks Jhaliya :)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense to release `item` as that would mean you've taken ownership only once and you're relinquishing it. So the `currentItem` will be pointing to a deallocated object. You will have to take ownership by retaining the object and later releasing it once you're done with the object.

Comment: but doing `currentItem = item` doesn't retain it. If the property is declared as `retain` you should do as Jhaliya mentioned i.e. `self.currentItem = item`.

Comment: I have retained in the header.

Comment: Yeah I understood that part. Are you saying that by declaring a `retain`ed property, doing `currentItem = item` is sufficient for `currentItem` to retain the object pointed to by `item`?

Comment: Well, `currentItem = item` is a simple assignment as you would do in any other language. Doing `self.currentItem = item` retains it because it invokes the method `setCurrentItem:` (and this is implicit) which takes care of releasing the old value held and retaining the newer value if the property is defined as `retain`. It will copy if it is a `copy` property. This `setCurrentItem:` method is automatically generated based on how the property is defined.